# Источник данных веб-сервис. Какие есть приемы для реализации приложения

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-webforms

Какие есть приемы для реализации приложения ASP.NET WebForms/MVC, если источник данных веб-сервис. Это подразумевает не использование стандартной схемы, а что-то другое. Стандартная схема, это SqlClient для взаимодействия с БД, потом приведение к какой-то модели полученных данных и биндинг в серверном контроле массива данных полученных из БД. Если небольшие наборы данных для какого-то списка не сложно реализовать силами jquery ajax, и перевод json данных теми же силами jquery в разметку html, то как быть с деревьями и таблицами? При этом хотелось бы использовать серверные продвинутые контролы, такие как например ASPxGridView DevExpress.

Есть мысли использовать HttpClient класс, но нужно в дальнейшем реализовывать логику хранения данных, чтобы не дергать сервис постоянно. Если к БД запросы это нормально, т.к. в основном и БД и IIS на одном сервере, то тут данные гоняются по http. Нет каких либо практик, как реализовать правильно такое приложение. Класс приложения - интернет магазин, что подразумевает в каких-то местах глубокое кеширование(т.е. практически не меняются), например номер телефона, а есть данные, например цены и акции, которые должны обновляться периодически.

Answer (score 1):

Я в одном из проектов делал так.
MVC использовал для навигации и выдачи HTML страниц с JavaScript скриптами вся логика работы с API была в Angular контроллерах, MVC контроллеры при этом были пустые и база данных не используется.

Получать данные из API а потом хранить в таблице: Всё зависит от задачи, но тут два минуса, нужно будет постоянно актуализировать данные, а выигрыша в производительности не вижу, т.к. клиенту всё равно запрашивать данные с вашего сервера или с API.